# Objective-c HackerRank How to read two line inputs

Tags: objective-c

For this problem on hack rank it requires two line input.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation/problem

Input

5 4

1 2 3 4 5

How can I read both lines.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main()
{
char *word;
scanf("%[^\n]s",word);
NSString* word2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, World.\n%@",[NSString stringWithCString:word encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
printf("%s", [word2 cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
return 0;
}
```

This is getting the first line but how would I read the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets(word, ..., stdin) instead of scanf. Make sure to trim the trailing \n.

Your code should normally crash as word is pointing anywhere but not to a buffer you should overwrite. Use char word[100] or whatever length you need instead.